# button click event to create new asp.net combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, button, combobox

I have an existing drop down list(namely ddlA). On selecting a value in which, I am getting a cascading drop down list(ddlB). The requirement is, I need to create a button on the webform. By clicking the button, I would need to create drop down list dynamically of type ddlA. But here is the tricky part, I am required to present all the values in this dropdown except the selected value in the previous selection(s) of type ddlA.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<DropDownList> DDLList = new List<DropDownList>();
        Session["DDLs"] = DDLList;
    }
    else
    {
        List<DropDownList> existingDropDowns = (List<DropDownList>)Session["DDLs"];
        //Add all existing DropDownLists to Panel
        foreach (DropDownList dropdown in existingDropDowns)
        {
            Panel1.Controls.Add(dropdown);
            dropdown.AutoPostBack = true;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }
        Session["DDLs"] = existingDropDowns;
    }
}
```

and here is my button click event code:

```
protected void ddlAdditionBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<DropDownList> existingDropDowns = (List<DropDownList>)Session["DDLs"];
    DropDownList newDropDown = new DropDownList();
    newDropDown.ID = "DDL" + existingDropDowns.Count.ToString();           
    existingDropDowns.Add(newDropDown);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(newDropDown);
    newDropDown.AutoPostBack = true;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    Session["DDLs"] = existingDropDowns;
}
```

Below is the code to connect the existing dropdown list with the database.

```
protected void GetDropDowndata()
{
    DataTable ddlData= lookupCache.AccessLookupData(Constants.GroupSelectionFilter.ToString());
    if (ddlData != null && ddlData.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlData.DefaultView.Sort = "DropDownValue";
        ddlData = groupsData.DefaultView.ToTable();

        ddlSelectGrp.DataSource = ddlData;
        ddlSelectGrp.DataTextField = "DropDownValue";//ddlSelectGrp is the existing dropdown id
        ddlSelectGrp.DataValueField = "DropDownBoxID";
        ddlSelectGrp.DataMember = "DropDownGroup";
        ddlSelectGrp.DataBind();
        ddlSelectGrp.Items.Insert(1, Constants.GroupAll.ToString());
        ddlSelectGrp.SelectedIndex = 1;
        btnGroupSave.Enabled = true;
        btnGroupSave.CssClass = "saveButton";               
    }
}
```

But I have no idea on how to connect the dynamically generated dropdownlist with the datasource and that too without the selected value(s) in the previous dropdown list(s).

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am able to create the dropdown list with the button click. But i have no idea how to present with updated values in it.

Comment: it's like i selected 'a' from a,b,c in the existing dropdown. Now after creating the dropdown via the button, I need to show b,c as values in the newly created dropdown list.

Comment: @Sami , Sorry for the delay.Here it is..